# What happens with Poison Counters in Two Headed Giant?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

I know that in Commander, 10 poison counters kills a player.

However, does the same apply in Two Headed Giant?

There are technically two players, even though they share a life total of 30.

Also I believe counters would only be placed on the targeted player of an attacking infect creature.

What are the conditions for losing due to infect in THG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Two-Headed Giant you need 15 or more poison counters. See [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020180119.pdf).

> 704.5t In a Two-Headed Giant game, if a team has **fifteen or more poison counters**, that team loses the game. See rule 810, “Two-Headed
> Giant Variant.”

Also

> 810.5. With the exception of life total and poison counters, a team’s resources (cards in hand, mana, and so on) are not shared in the
> Two-Headed Giant variant. Teammates may review each other’s hands and
> discuss strategies at any time. Teammates can’t manipulate each
> other’s cards or permanents.

You share those poision counters as a team. So if your teammate is
being hit for 5 poison counters, your team has 5 poison counters.

> 810.8a Players win and lose the game only as a team, not as individuals. **If either player on a team loses the game, the team loses
> the game. If either player on a team wins the game, the entire team
> wins the game.** If an effect says that a player can’t win the game,
> that player’s team can’t win the game. If an effect says that a player
> can’t lose the game, that player’s team can’t lose the game.

You win as a team, you lose as a team. There is no 'I' in team.

Further **clarification** regarding poison counters in Two-Headed Giant.

> 810.10. Effects that cause players to get poison counters happen to each player individually. The poison counters are shared by the team.
>
> 810.10a If an effect needs to know how many poison counters an individual player has, that effect uses the number of poison counters
> that player’s team has. If an effect needs to know how many poison
> counters a player’s opponents have, that effect uses the number of
> poison counters opposing teams have.
>
> 810.10b If an effect says that a player loses poison counters, that player’s team loses that many poison counters.
>
> 810.10c If an effect says that a player can’t get poison counters, no player on that player’s team can get poison counters.
>
> 810.10d If a rule or effect needs to know what kinds of counters an individual player has, that effect uses the kinds of counters that
> player has and the kinds of counters that player’s team has. A player
> is “poisoned” if his or her team has one or more poison counters.